# Bind ASP.NET Web API response to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

As the title says, I am trying to take the response from a Web API and bind it to a dropdownlist. Is there anyway to do this using the `HttpClient` method described in their [documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)? The API is returning a list of objects in `JSON` format.

Here is my code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyURI");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("Resource").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        dynamic content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //Somehow bind to DropDown
        //MyDdl.DataSource = content;
    }
}
```

I was considering trying to convert it to a `DataTable` in order to bind, but it seems like a lot of effort to do that.

**UPDATE**

This is what is being returned from

```
[
   {"ID":"1","Name":"Bob","Authorizations":[]},
    ...
]
```

Note how one of the properties `Authorizations` is a list in and of itself, i'm assuming i'll have to iterate through and omit that property in order to bind the DropDown with `DataTextField = Name` and `DataValueField = ID`.

Comment: Is the front end Webforms?

Comment: @Pharylon Yup, WebForms.

Comment: Can you paste the content you receive from the statement response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind directly to that object without even bothering to cast it to something meaningful, by doing:

```
var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
MyDdl.DataSource = content;
MyDdl.DataTextField = "Name";
MyDdl.DataValueField = "ID";
MyDdl.DataBind();
```

The data binding does all the work of reflecting on the objects.

If you're using `JavaScriptSerializer` or something else other than JSON.NET, you may have to do some more work, but JSON.NET handles simple data like this pretty well.